# Use path-style amazon aws sdk go

Tags: go, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-go

I'm using some aws-sdk-go functionalities in my app, and it creates DNS  style hosts to request, like `somebucket.mys3.com`. But I have some DNS issues and want to receive the requests in path-style, like `mys3.com/somebucket`. How can I config the SDK to generates it requests in path-style mode?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the `aws.Config` set the `S3ForcePathStyle` to `true`, ie

```
ses, err := session.NewSession(
   &aws.Config{
      S3ForcePathStyle: aws.Bool(true),
      ...
   }
)
```